# Google doesn't search my amp pages

Tags: amp-html

This is the original url of this page - http://www.vikatan.com/news/india/63251-during-the-day-dont-cook-bihar-govt-order.art

This is my amp page related to it - http://www.vikatan.com/other/summer_article.amp.html

The above amp page is static page which is include the original site content.

Is this possible google search my amp page. I just add the above amp page only. there is no amp related file existing in this folder.

anyone please help me.

Comment: If you have recently changed the code. It takes time to reflect on Google

Comment: No, i just add the amp page on 28.04.2016. My question is, Is it possible google search my amp page?

Answer (score 1):

your page http://www.vikatan.com/other/summer_article.amp.html links to a canonical page in this way:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.vikatan.com/news/india/63251-during-the-day-dont-cook-bihar-govt-order.art">
```

then the page http://www.vikatan.com/news/india/63251-during-the-day-dont-cook-bihar-govt-order.art links to an AMP page which is the different from the one above:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://www.vikatan.com/article_amp.php?aid=63251">
```

Make sure that the linking between canonical and amphtml pages is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found the solution for this. Now it's workine fine. But some errors occured in this page.